# PageKeyedDataSource with setInitialKey

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-paging-library

Which method in PageKeyedDataSource will be called when I set initialKey on PagedList?
`PagedList<Employee> pagedList = new PagedList.Builder<>(dataSource, config)
       .setMainThreadExecutor(new MainThreadExecutor())
       .setBackgroundThreadExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
       .setInitialKey(50)
       .build();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.setInitialKey doesn't affect to PageKeyedDataSource. PageKeyedDataSource will call loadInitial method even if you pass value 10000.